# I decided to use sashido for migration of my parse server code but getting error the module twillo not found

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

How can I use twillo sms service which was predefined module in parse while migrating parse cloud to sashido as in parse twillo is predefined.

Followed by this link :
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/get-started-with-twilio-and-parse-in-the-twilio-cloud-module.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SashiDo you don't have to give up on the convenience of using Twilio. Here is what you should do in order to use it:

1. add twilio's Noje.js module in package.json
2. simply use require() as before

You can do the same with other packages - we have Advanced Cloud Code and you can use it for this purpose.